# Geometry must be a Point or LineString error using Cartopy

Tags: python, cartopy

I'm trying to run a simple Cartopy example:

```
   import cartopy.crs as ccrs
   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
   ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
   ax.coastlines()
   plt.show()
```

But I'm getting this error:

Geometry must be a Point or LineString
`python: geos_ts_c.cpp:4179: int GEOSCoordSeq_getSize_r(GEOSContextHandle_t, const geos::geom::CoordinateSequence*, unsigned int*): Assertion`0 != cs' failed`.

I installed Cartopy using miniconda3: `conda install -c conda-forge cartopy`
I also tried to install Cartopy with pip (in a virtual environment), but I get the same error.
My OS is Debian Buster.

Any idea?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The problem is a wrong version of shapely, with Cartopy the binary package shoudn't be used, it should be built from source instead.
This is explained [here](https://pypi.org/project/Shapely/) and [here](https://github.com/SciTools/cartopy/issues/871).

So I did:

```
pip uninstall shapely
pip install shapely --no-binary shapely
```

Comment: Thanks! so my Colab command was: ```!pip uninstall -y shapely```
```!pip install shapely --no-binary shapely```